# Laravel forms broken after including Vue

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

I am in the process of adding real-time messaging functionality to a Laravel 6.x site. The messaging seems to be working, but as soon as I include `<div id="app">` just after the main menu, some of the existing forms stop working. E.g., this form:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-controls">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form id="form-status{{$task->id}}" action="{{ url('xxx') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
          @csrf
          <label for="status{{$task->id}}">Status: </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="status{{$task->id}}" name="status">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Not started</option>
            <option value="10">Started</option>
            <option value="20">Finished</option>
          </select>
        </form>                                                                    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">   
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('{{'form-status'.$task->id}}').submit();"> Update 
  </a>
</div>
```

The post action is still executed, but I get a 419 "page expired" error, so I assume the csrf value is not sent with the post data anymore.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? For now, I've moved the APP id to a small section of the website with no pre-existing forms, but in future I would like to have more Vue components on the page, so I will have to fix it at some stage.

I am using Bootstrap 3, so I removed Bootstrap 4 in Laravel using npm, and I import it using a script tag. The HTML header includes:

```
  <link href="http://myurl/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://myurl/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://myurl/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://myurl/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://myurl/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Script imported for laravel echo and vue -->
  <script src="http://myurl/js/app.js" defer></script>
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"  defer></script>
  <script src="http://myurl/js/bootstrap.min.js"  defer></script>
  <script src="http://myurl/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" defer></script>
```

Thanks, 
Hendrik.

EDIT:
The html sent to the client is as follows:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-controls">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form id="form-status94" action="myurl/projects/35/nodes/68/tasks/94/status" method="POST" style="display: none;">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="7ynFCghH2yNGpaO5Pfpd45EMYGIQHdXdNjYooNtJ">
          <label for="status94">Status: </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="status94" name="status">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Not started</option>
            <option value="10">Started</option>
            <option value="20">Finished</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('form-status94').submit();">Update
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your curly braces conflict with Vue.js. There's a [Blade & JavaScript Frameworks](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks) section in Laravel's documentation, saying:

> Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the `@` symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched. For example:
>
> ```html
> <h1>Laravel</h1>
>
> Hello, @{{ name }}.
> ```
>
> In this example, the `@` symbol will be removed by Blade; however, `{{ name }}` expression will remain untouched by the Blade engine, allowing it to instead be rendered by your JavaScript framework.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please see my above edit with html seen in the browser. It seems as though the html is fine.